# Springboot external api call request and response capture in database

Tags: java, spring-boot, design-patterns, microservices, software-design

From my backend application(**springboot, java8**) i will make multiple external api call's. I have a requirement to log all the requests and response data's (including headers, request and response body) into database(**MongoDB**).

Below is my sample code, this how i am trying to capture request and responses on each external api calls. On exception i will store status as 'FAILED'.

In my project multiple modules will be added on new 3rd party api integration, so in each module for every different external api calls i have to capture all the requests and reponses like this. I am not satisfied with below approach. Kindly suggest best approach to solve this.

**Sample Service layer method**

```
public ResponseDTOFromExternalApi externalApiCallServiceMethod(String clientId, RequestDTO requestDTO) {

        ExternalApiCallRequestObj externalApiCallRequestObj = prepareExternalApiRequestObjFromRequestDTO(requestDTO);
        ApiCall apiCall = ApiCall.builder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .status("SUBMITTED")
                .requestPayload(externalApiCallRequestObj)
                .build();

        apiCall = apiCallRepository.save(apiCall);

        ExternalApiCallReponseObj externalApiCallReponseObj = externalApiCallService.callExternalApi1(externalApiCallRequestObj);

        apiCall = apiCallRepository.findById(apiCall.getId());

        apiCall.setResponsePayload(externalApiCallReponseObj);
        apiCall.setStatus("COMPLETED");

        apiCallRepository.save(apiCall);

        return toDTO(externalApiCallReponseObj);
}
```

**Sample Domain for api calls**

```
@Document("api_calls")
@Builder
@Data
public class ApiCall {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String clientId;

    private String status;

    private Object requestPayload;

    private Object responsePayload;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use Spring AOP to address this cross cutting concern.

Assuming `ExternalApiCallService` is a spring managed bean , following code will intercept all the `callExternalApi1()` and can log the same to database.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class ExternalCallLoggerAspect {

    @Autowired
    ApiCallRepository apiCallRepository;

    @Pointcut("execution(* *..ExternalApiCallService.callExternalApi1(..))")
    public void externalApiCallService(){}


    @Around("externalApiCallService() && args(request)")
    public ExternalApiCallReponseObj logCalls(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,ExternalApiCallRequestObj request){

      Object result=null;
      String status = "COMPLETED";
      ExternalApiCallReponseObj response = null;

        // Build the apiCall from request 
        ApiCall apiCall = ApiCall.builder()
                .clientId(clientId)
                .status("SUBMITTED")
                .requestPayload(request)
                .build();

        //save the same to db
        apiCall = apiCallRepository.save(apiCall);

        // Proceed to call the external Api and get the result
        try {
           result = pjp.proceed();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
           status = "FAILED";
        }

        //Update the response           
        apiCall = apiCallRepository.findById(apiCall.getId());            
        apiCall.setStatus(status);
        apiCallRepository.save(apiCall);

        if(result != null) {
          response = (ExternalApiCallReponseObj)result;
          apiCall.setResponsePayload(response);
        }

        //continue with response
        return response;
    }

}
```

Note

1.There is a typo with the name `ExternalApiCallReponseObj`

2.The aspect code is verified that it works and the logic was included later on untested. Please make the required corrections

Ideally the original method should be stripped down to this

```
public ResponseDTOFromExternalApi externalApiCallServiceMethod(String clientId, RequestDTO requestDTO) {

       return toDTO(externalApiCallService.callExternalApi1(prepareExternalApiRequestObjFromRequestDTO(requestDTO)));
}
```

More about Spring AOP [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop)

---

**Update :** on a second thought , if all the external api calls are through a single method , say `ExternalApiCallService.callExternalApi1()` , this logging logic can be moved to that common point , isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

Spring's WebClient already has the ability to log all request and response data by adding exchange filters.

By using it for your network requests the only thing left to do is to write this information in your mongodb.

Here is tutorial on logging requests and responses:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-log-webclient-calls

Cheers